# How to sum datetime on a dynamic pivot and represent it in HH:MM:SS

Tags: sql-server

So my goal is to setup a procedure to be later used on a vb.net app, this procedure needs to get the text of a tag(row) and the name of an association (column), and sum the time between the both of the entry table (only need help with formatting the datetime).

It's currently showing the time in secs and I want it to show in HH:MM:SS format.

Sample data table 
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=9c9c01fb1bdfe75929679114d8d7e799

```
DECLARE @col VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @col = COALESCE(@col + ', ','') + QUOTENAME(NomeE)

FROM dbo.Emprensa as E GROUP BY E.NomeE  

SELECT @col 

SET @sql = '
select  Texto,' + @col + '
from  (select  E.NomeE, T.Texto, datediff(second, En.StartT,En.EndT ) as secs 
       from dbo.Emprensa as E 
  inner join dbo.Entry as En on E.IDEmp = En.IDEmp
  inner join dbo.Tag as T on T.IDTag = En.IDTag)p

PIVOT( sum(secs)  FOR NomeE IN ( ' + @col + ' )) AS pvt

 order by Texto
 '
PRINT @sql
EXEC (@sql)
```

600 want it to show 00:10:00

4200 want it to show 01:10:00

Comment: Could you have more than 24 hours?

Answer (score 0):

Total blind guess, as no sample data, however, ***assuming*** that my guess of the syntax is correct and that it can't go over 24 hours:

```
DECLARE @col nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @coltime nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX);

SELECT @col = COALESCE(@col + N', ',N'') + QUOTENAME(NomeE)
FROM dbo.Emprensa as E
GROUP BY E.NomeE;

SELECT @coltime = COALESCE(@col + N', ',N'') + N'DATEADD(SECOND,' + QUOTENAME(NomeE) + N',CONVERT(time,''00:00:00'')'
FROM dbo.Emprensa as E
GROUP BY E.NomeE;


SET @sql = N'
SELECT Texto,' + @coltime + N'
FROM (SELECT E.NomeE, T.Texto, datediff(second, En.StartT,En.EndT ) as secs 
      FROM dbo.Emprensa as E 
           INNER JOIN dbo.Entry as En on E.IDEmp = En.IDEmp
           INNER JOIN dbo.Tag as T on T.IDTag = En.IDTag)p

PIVOT( SUM(secs)  FOR NomeE IN ( N' + @col + N')) AS pvt
order by Texto';

PRINT @sql
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Hi @Larnu ty so much for your answer, unfortunately its giving me some syntax errors, ill update my question with my data and yes it cannot go over 24 hours.

Comment: Done, i tryed to use the table format as used on other answers, but to no avail since i suck xD

Comment: Without a sample, and means to replicate (you haven't told me the errors either and I'm not a kind reader :) ) I can't help @RubenMoreira .

Comment: I am really sry if i am not being useful to the situation, whats the best course of action so this question could be useful for someone in the future, shall i post the insert querys? Not really getting what you mean about sample, i tought it was the tables. ty so much for your quick replys and patience.

Comment: Yes, data for your tables in what I'm talking about here. Either in formatted `text` or as DDL and DML statements, that I can use to replicate the problem. And don't forget the error message.

Comment: Would a sql fiddle suffice, just found out about the site dont know if its good to use or not. ty for your patience! :)

Comment: Hope it helps https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=9c9c01fb1bdfe75929679114d8d7e799

Comment: Btw thank you for your help thus far, im currently 2 weeks deep in sql so for me this part is really dificult just getting the dynamic part operational was a total shit storm, legit browsed over 25 questions on SO and managed to get it working by adapting the various answers i´ve found.

Comment: SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(second,datediff(second,StartT,EndT),0),108),8) as secs
from entry                                                                                                            
 is there any way to put this line of code on the pivot it does what i want just when i put it on the pivot it makes it error becuse its a varchar on the sum, and also doesnt let me convert it at the end ! :(

Comment: i´ve had an idea ill try combine your code to mine and see if it works, if it works bless your soul kind stranger!